# Is an Adjustable Stiffness Flexure Spring possible?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, springs, flexures

I have recently discovered flexure springs (see image below), and I am interested in using one in an amateur project I am building.

However, I would prefer if I am able to adjust the "stiffness" of the flexure spring, to allow the spring to bear different loads.

Despite extensive searching online, I have not found a flexure spring design that provides flexible or adaptable stiffness.

Is it possible to have a flexure spring, the stiffness of which, can be adjusted?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean torsional spring?

Comment: @ShadowMan No, torsional springs are quite different from flexure springs (see image attached in my question).

Comment: I saw your picture. So then do you load that spring in a direction perpendicular to it's plane?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: This is probably well beyond a hobbyist approach. But a few magneto-rheological rubber bearings could provide a 'tuneable' spring constant.

Comment: You can add holes with tapered threads and a tapered nut.

Comment: You could look into adding additional of these units either in series or parallel and device some way of making them easy to take out.

Comment: There are helical springs with variable pitch, whose stiffness changes with preload, i.e. stiffen as they are compressed, and the preload can be screw-adjusted to vary the stiffness in the assembly. Maybe scissor mechanisms, where the angle can be varied, could be a possibility. The stiffness of compressed air depends on pressure. Leaf springs can be effectively shortened and thus stiffened with movable supports...

Comment: With the spring that is shown, I imagine a second disc would be required, to partially remove the flexibility from some length of the cutout, by immobilizing variable locations in the main disc, relative to either the inside or outside ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case the adjustable stiffens can be archived by modifying the shape from the spring. If you use different stiffens and allow some blocking this can be achieved. See screenshot.
[image]